# Automating web page population

Tags: automation, uipath

I have data in a csv file & want to do the following with it:

1. Log into web site
2. Populate field of the page with the csv data
3. Navigate to next page
4. Input the rest of data
5. Click submit
6. Repeat for next line

I can do this using UiPath but it's an expensive option for a relatively simple use case.

Any one any suggestions on how do this using a different method?

Thanks,

EddieT

Comment: Not sure what you really need. Did you already do the UiPath Academy for learning the basics?

Comment: Hi, This is a single use case that involves populating web forms with structured data from csv file so just researching if I can do this without UiPath ( which is proven but expensive ). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for alternatives then you probably would want to investigate APIs or Webhooks. But that all depends on the access rights you have for that particular website.

Try messaging the Developers of the website you need as they might have this service already available.

UiPath may appear expensive but if you calculate the amount of time saved for this one process then you will see the money savings too.
If you can find a couple of other processes you want to automate then I'd highly recommend it.